# View counter using IP address in Django app

Tags: django, view, counter

I am working on Django app and I want to know how many people use it, so I decided to add view counter on the page. I created view counter (watched some tutorial) but it doesn't work. I don't know where is a problem. Here is the code:

models.py:

```js
class User(models.Model):
    user=models.TextField(default=None)
    def __str__(self):
        return self-user
```

admin.py:

```js
admin.site.register(User)
```

There is a problem with views.py. It says that "return can be used only within a function". I know that but what can I do to make this work?

```js
def get_ip(request):
    address=request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if address:
        ip=address.split(',')[-1].strip()
    else:
        ip=request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip

    ip=get_ip(request)
    u=User(user=ip)
    print(ip)
    result=User.objects.filter(Q(user__icontains=ip))
    if len(result)==1:
        print("user exist")
    elif len(result)>1:
        print("user exist more...")
    else:
        u.save()
        print("user is unique")
    count=User.objects.all().count()
    print("total user is", count)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'count':count})
```

index.html:

```html
{% load static %}
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World Django App</title>
  </head>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <div>Total visits: {{count}} </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is glaring. You have two return statements that are not conditional in single function.

Your error is:

```
return ip
```

Remove that.

I noticed, you mean to make two different functions because you're erroneously calling your current function to return an ip.

What you should make a view function and then call get_ip in it.
Remove everything from ip=get_ip down.
Put them in a get view function.

The new function is what you should put in your urls file

Comment: thank you, now there is no error anymore. but counter still doesnt't work. do you know where is a problem?

Comment: I noticed something else... I'll make an edit

Comment: You can mark my answer as the answer if you don't mind

Comment: do you know how can I use this count variable ({{count}} in index.html page) in all of my html pages of my Django app?

Comment: Always send it in the context variable.